# Matrix solving problem

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a linear system like this:
$$\left[\begin{array}{l}x_2\\y_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{l}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}x_1\\y_1\end{array}\right]$$
$A_{11},A_{12},A_{21},A_{22}$ are known.
The target is to get the matrix:
$$\left[\begin{array}{l}y_1\\y_2\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{l}B_{11}&B_{12}\\B_{21}&B_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]$$. For 2-by-2 matrix, I can solve it manually. But now I have a 4-by-4(6-by-6) matrix which I have to use Mathematica to get answer. Any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Hi. It is not clear how the unknown variables are shuffled in 4-by-4 or 6-by-6 cases. Can you write the above two equations, say, for the 4-by-4 case?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(Format[#[n__]] := Subscript[#, Row[{n}]]) & /@ {a, x, y};

eqns = Thread[{x[2], y[2]} == Array[a, {2, 2}] . {x[1], y[1]}]
```

[image]

```
sol = Collect[Solve[eqns, {y[1], y[2]}][[1]], {x[1], x[2]}]
```

[image]

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)

B = List @@@ Values[sol] /. {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's what I need!!

Comment: Hello Bob, I have a question about the slot substitution: (Format[#[n__]] := Subscript[#, Row[{n}]]) & /@ {a, x, y}; &/@{a,x,y} means the slot # could be substituted by any of array members {a,x,y}, is this understanding correct? What's the function of "/@" here?

Comment: And I have another question about the last step map apply. Why List@@@[expr] can split the y1,y2 with substitution x1->1 x2->1 into two matrix cells? Thank you very much!

Comment: `f /@ {a, x, y}` maps `f` onto the list  (evaluates to `{f[a], f[x], f[y]}`). In the first instance, `f` is the pure function `(Format[#[n__]] := Subscript[#, Row[{n}]]) &` The slots are filled with each of the elements of the list. `Values[sol] /. {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1}` is a vector with the form `{b11 + b12, b21 + b22}`. `MapApply`: `f @@@ expr` replaces heads at level 1 of `expr` by `f`. In this case, the head `Plus` is replaced by `List`, converting the vector into  the matrix `{{b11, b12}, {b21, b22}}`.

Comment: AH!! Plus is a head, I need to find a book to study Wolfram language. Thank you very much, Bob!